# Speedy evaluation of function on Matrix element

Tags: r

Let say I have below calculation

```
my_fn = Vectorize(function(x, y) x + y)
x_vec = y_vec = c(0.10, 0.20)
Matrix = expand.grid(x_vec, y_vec)
```

Now I want to apply `my_fn()` on each row

```
my_fn(Matrix[,1], Matrix[,2])
```

I am wondering if there is any speeder method if number of rows `Matrix` is very big e.g. `1,000,000`

Comment: All mathematical signs are vectorized. So your function is the same as `Matrix[,1] + Matrix[,2]`

Comment: In general, `apply(your_dataframe,1,yourfunction)` applies a function rowbase. But for your case it is not necessary.

Comment: @Sotos `my_fn ` is just an example on what I am trying to achieve. My actual function is quite complex

Comment: Then maybe try it with Reduce, i.e. `Reduce('your_fun', Matrix)`

Comment: Speeding it up would depend very much on your actual function.